# Can Server validate Client application to ensure no code changes have been made?

Tags: java, security, validation, build, client

It may not be possible, but I would like my Server application to not only validate username and password, but also validate that the Client application has not been modified.

I would like to generate an identifier that changes with each build, yet stays the same for multiple runs of the same build.

I tried:

```
File jarFile = new File(this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI());
int theID = jarFile.lastModified());
```

But the time stamp gets changed when placed on different machines.

I'd like to have a Validate.class that generates the private ID.  The Validate.class is sent to the Server which compares the Validate.class to its own version of the class, and then validates the ID contained in the class.  Would this work in theory?  Or

Comment: The motivated hacker might use a network packet sniffer to analyze what data is being sent to the server and mimic that traffic in an entirely new app.

Comment: That's inherently impossible.  An attacker can spoof whatever he wants.

Comment: Some instant messenger (Yahoo I think) once required that the client could provide a hashkey of any range of the distributed binary that it claimed to be.  This essentially meant that the distributed binary had to be included in any open source reimplementation which the license forbade.  You could consider something similar.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen This doesn't make things much harder, as a new, modified, client could simply maintain a copy of the original client and compute the requested hash on that. You can make the job of an attacker wanting to modify/replace a client harder, but you cannot make it impossible (in fact, here, maintaining a copy of the original, is not adding any real difficulty to an attacker - there are techniques that can make this harder, such as including a nonce from the server in the hash computation, but again, once the attacker figures out what's going, it's easy to beat).

Comment: @jeffsix Yes.  This is relatively easy for a Java program.  The question here, is whether this might be good enough?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Of course...everything is a risk decision! It does make things a bit more difficult, but does not provide any serious protection. If all the OP is concerned about are simple attacks, then yes, you can make it pretty difficult to reverse engineer what's going on (especially if you use a nonce sent from the server that is used in the client-code hash computation, as I outlined above). If you're concerned enough about this risk to go to this level, you've got to be assuming a significant threat, that could easily beat it, or your risk analysis is probably off.

Comment: But, of course, that's something only the OP can decide as it's up to him to make a proper risk analysis and decide if implementing such a countermeasure is called for based on the limited protection is offers.

Answer (score 0):

No. You cannot do this. The client is making a computation on itself and sending that to the server. All an attacker would need to do is study what is being sent from the legitimate client (be that a hardcoded value or a computation performed by the client) and then simply repeat that value (or computation) when they are making their own connection to the server.

Comment: You may be right.  But I was thinking that by only accepting the value from within the Validate.class, even if the hacker knew the key they would have to hardcode the key into the Validate.class which would cause an exception when they tried to send that class to the Server.

Comment: You're assuming the client will send the actual class that it's using and not the legitimate one that your server is expecting. Basic tenant of client/server security: an attacker can always find out everything your client is doing and can mimic it in server interactions.

Answer (score 0):

Not easily, since any part of the program you used to do this check could be made to lie and say it passed.

What you want is a feature called [remote attestation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Computing#Remote_attestation) where some piece of hardware/software attests to a third party that the  system is in  a particular state. The only way to do this is used a piece of hardware called a [Trusted Platform Module](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Platform_Module)  However, this limits  your application to users running certain versions of window or maybe redhat linux, and people with hardware TPMs. In short, unless your writing this forthe NSA, its not worth it.